# Laptop USB-C to display HDMI does not work

Tags: drivers, display, hdmi, usb-c

I use an HP Pavilion 15 Laptop with Windows 11 Home. My HDMI port has sadly been mechanically broken ever since my laptop fell down a few months ago. I want to use my Samsung C27F396FHU as a second monitor and I have a USB-C [laptop] to HDMI [display] cable.

Somehow this does not work. Windows gives me a "device not recognised" error (no error code) about 10sec after I plug the USB-C in. With my phone instead of my laptop or my friends Macbook this works, so the error is with my laptop not the cable or monitor. On this website https://www.samsung.com/de/support/model/LC27F396FHUXEN/ I found a driver to reinstall (though in the process it only alows HDMI or analog as choices, but since in the monitor it is HDMI, this is what I tried), it still does not work. Restarting, updating and checking the drivers in "devices" also changes nothing (all up to date).

Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: [The device has to support HDMI Alt Mode, if it does not, then what you want isn't possible with your hardware.](https://www.hdmi.org/spec/typec).  There really isn't a solution to a problem like this, if the system has physical damage to the HDMI port, all sort of things could have happen to the circuit (although I suspect your device simply does not support HDMI Alt mode to be honest).

Comment: We need the precise model number. Your computer needs USB-C 3.1 Rev 2 or later to support a display [known as DisplayPort alt mode]. At least some Pavilion 15s have only Rev 1, which can't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your awnsers! I have a model 15-cs1xxx. I dont know where to find the last 3 digits but I found out that a similar model only has Rev1 so I gues this is the same for mine too... Thank you anyway!

Comment: There is no such thing as "USB-C 3.1 Rev 2". It also does not need HMDI Alt Mode because exactly nobody uses that, it's always DisplayPort, sometimes converted to HDMI. // You need a USB-C connector that supports DisplayPort Alt Mode. If it's not in the specs you're out of luck.

Comment: Somewhere on your laptop there will be a label with the exact model number or a service tag that you can use to look up the exact model number.

Comment: Ah okay it was physically written on the back of my laptop... thanks! My model number is cs1104ng.

Comment: All USB ports are "Gen 1". Does that mean it can not work?

Comment: I bet if you purchased a USB-C to HDMI adapter from amazon and you just used a regular HDMI cable instead it will work

Answer (score 1):

What kind of USB (the data protocol) the USB-C port can do is not relevant. Instead, the port must support DisplayPort Alt Mode. On most notebooks, this support is limited to only some of the ports, if it is supported at all. Notebooks generally do not support HDMI Alt Mode.

You indicate your model number is *15-cs1104ng*, its [spec sheet is available here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06378276). Unfortunately, it confirms that this port does not support DisplayPort Alt Mode:

> 1 USB Type-C™ 3.1 Gen 1 (***Data Transfer Only***, 5 Gb/s signaling rate)

(Emphasis mine)

The adapter you got also works with DisplayPort Alt Mode, converting it to HDMI internally. Except perhaps if it was made for Android phones (about the only thing actually using HDMI Alt Mode). If it’s listed as compatible with MacBook and iPad, you’re on the right track, generally. Not for your notebook unfortunately.

With the sole display output (HDMI) broken, this leaves you with a single remaining option: A DisplayLink USB graphics solution. It is only suitable for office work and perhaps some video playback.

Answer (score 1):

You can try holding down the power button of your laptop for 30 seconds without any external devices connected (including the power source) to release static electricity. After that, the HDMI port of the HP USB-C Universal Hub would work successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).